# Need help in creating the scheduling service

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, task

I need to create a scheduling service which will poll the database after a specific time interval, pick the required objects and send it to a WCF service to perform the required task.

Shall I use the windows worker thread? or is there any other ready to use component that windows / third party provides?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create a windows service... and in that run a timer that will fire an even on specific interval... this allows you to run your code at specific interval... without any user interaction..